# Find all the blocks

Tags: python, list, nested

I am very new to python and coding. I have this homework that I have to do:

You will receive on the first line the rows of the matrix (n) and on the next n lines you will get each row of the matrix as a string (zeros and ones separated by a single space). You have to calculate how many blocks you have (connected ones horizontally or diagonally) Here are examples:

```
Input:
5
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
Output:
2

Input:
6
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
Output:
1

Input:
4
0 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
Output:
5
```

the code I came up with for now is :

```
n = int(input())
blocks = 0

matrix = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(n)]

#loop or something to find the blocks in the matrix

print(blocks)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "connected ones horizontally or diagonally" would be 4 or 6 blocks (depending on precise definition) in the first example.

Comment: These are the examples i had been given from the lector.

Comment: And exactly that definition of a "block"?

Comment: The text is 100% copy/paste from the doc file.

Comment: I think I got it: Every 1 which can be reached from an existing block horizontally or diagonally belongs to the same block. So the algorithm would be to start with an arbitrary 1, mark it to belong to a block (or set it just 0) and then go horizontally and diagonally along other 1s and mark them as part of same block. If no more connected 1 can be found, find another 1 to start a new block until you can't find any more 1s.

Comment: will try it as soon as i can get to the laptop. the basic idea i had was with for loop and : if matrix[i][j] == 1 and matrix[i][j+1] == 1 and matrix[i+1][j] == 1 and matrix[i+1][j+1] == 1 i have a block. but then again i was focusing on the first example only.

Comment: A block can be already a single 1 (as third example shows). It doesn't need to have 1s in all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def valid(y,x):
    if y>=0 and x>=0 and y<N and x<horizontal_len:
        return True

def find_blocks(y,x):
    Q.append(y)
    Q.append(x)

    #search around 4 directions (up, right, left, down)
    dy = [0,1,0,-1]
    dx = [1,0,-1,0]

    # if nothing is in Q then terminate counting block
    while Q:
        y = Q.pop(0)
        x = Q.pop(0)

        for dir in range(len(dy)):
            next_y = y + dy[dir]
            next_x = x + dx[dir]

            #if around component is valid range(inside the matrix) and it is 1(not 0) then include it as a part of block
            if valid(next_y,next_x) and matrix[next_y][next_x] == 1:
                Q.append(next_y)
                Q.append(next_x)
                matrix[next_y][next_x] = -1


N = int(input())

matrix = []
for rows in range(N):
   row = list(map(int, input().split()))
   matrix.append(row)

#row length
horizontal_len = len(matrix[0])

blocks = 0

#search from matrix[0][0] to matrix[N][horizontal_len]
for start_y in range(N):
    for start_x in range(horizontal_len):

        #if a number is 1 then start calculating
        if matrix[start_y][start_x] == 1:
            #make 1s to -1 for not to calculate again
            matrix[start_y][start_x] = -1
            Q=[]

            #start function
            find_blocks(start_y, start_x)
            blocks +=1

print(blocks)
```

I used BFS algorithm to solve this question. The quotations are may not enough to understand the logic. 
If you have questions about this solution, let me know!

Comment: Not up and down, only horizontally and diagonally.

Comment: Update: It actually passed the tests. We have a bunch of homeworks from easy to very hard and 1 week to do them before next batch and we submit them in a automated online system which does bunch of tests on the code and returns a score. This code passed 100/100.

Comment: @MinJae here is your code with some comments from me. Will be thankful for some explanation here and there. https://pastebin.com/TDMadvNq

Comment: Here is some explanation !! I hope this will help and if you want full review of how this process works.. let me know and i will give explanation as specific as possible..https://pastebin.com/hemGCh8i